# Resubscribing same shared observable inside flatMap of own data emits no data. By design?

Tags: rx-java2

Trying to migrate to `rx-java2`and came across a problem with resubscribing the shared observable inside it's own `flatMap`. Need this pattern to get-update-refresh chain:

1. Get current data from network (shared observable to avoid multiple network requests if source is being subscribed by several observers at the same time).
2. Modify the data and send it back to server (completable)
3. Get the data again after update completes

The whole thing looks like this:

```
@Test fun sharedTest() {
    val o = Observable.just(1).share()
    assertEquals(1, o
          .take(1)
          .flatMap({ 
             Completable.complete()
                        .andThen(o) })
          .blockingFirst())
}
```

The test fails with: `java.util.NoSuchElementException`
If `o` is not shared everything works.

That behavior seems to be because the latter subscriber comes when a single value of original has already been dispatched and only `onComplete` event is to be seen.

Does anybody know is that a by-design behavior and documented somehow? There is a workaround of course but I need to know the cause, as this is a bit annoying. The approach worked in Rx 1.x

Currently using version 2.1.3

#### Edit:

Seems to be no legitimate way to "restart" a shared observable and its side-effects as there is no guarantee other subscribers are not listening at the moment.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether the output from the `flatMap()` is supposed to be a) the original value of taken from `o` at that point, or b) the new value of `o` that has been modified, or c) restarting the observable `o` from the top.

Comment: @Bob Option c. Supposed to be a refreshed value and worked before (due to implementation specifics I guess). I have a net-disk-memory model based on concatenating respective observables instead of `o` in the real app. The network one is shared to prevent multiple network requests. The cache is being cleared within the `flatmap` after data modification request. Then if the original reads from network, the second subscription gets the same shared source because `take(1)` does not unsubscribe original at the moment the `flatMap` body evaluates and latter subscription gets only `onComplete`.

Comment: The shared observable with a single value emitted is a design flaw in my code as it is prone to race condition. Subscriber may come between value emission and a complete emission and get an empty result. Did not see it in a real world but the test above shows it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the bubble diagram for 'share' and you'll see why it behaves like that: [`Observable.share()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#share--).

share() emits items that are emitted after the subscription, it does not re-emit previously emitted items. Take a look at [`Observable.replay()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#replay--) for the behavior that should be what you expect.

Comment: No. Replay is not what's intended - a data refresh is needed inside `flatMap`. But I can't figure out how to unsubscribe the source to stop sharing of original observable (re-run side-effects). I've added `take(1)` to try to clarify. Seems like `take(1)` eagerly unsubscribed source before 2.x and keeps waiting at point of `flatMap` from now on...

Comment: I mean I don't (don't want to) know whether the source is hot or cold at my side. And can't figure out how to ensure (make it) cold and redo side-effects

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be no legitimate way to "restart" a shared observable and its side-effects as there is no guarantee other subscribers are not listening at the moment.